# integral apollonian sphere packing

Tags: fractals, packing-problem

Can a sequence of cotangent spheres be packed inside a sphere so that the reciprocals of all of the radii are integers, like the integral apollonian circle packings on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_packing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - see the "[bowl of integers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BowlofIntegers.html)". And if you want to go to higher dimensions, there's a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010324) of Graham et al.